# Group by and divide

Tags: sql, group-by

I have the table below on sql of accounting accounts (A is a cost account and B a headcount )  , and cc as cost center . So what i want to do is divide the amount of account A over account B for each cc

| Account | cc | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | x | 1 |
| A | y | 2 |
| B | z | 4 |
| B | y | 1 |
| A | z | 1 |
| B | x | 2 |

So the result would be :

| Account | cc | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | x | 1 /2 |
| A | y | 2 |
| B | z | 0 |
| B | y | 0 |
| A | z | 1 /4 |
| B | x | 0 |

I was thinking about a group by but Im a very beginner in sql and don't know how to use it thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please tag with appropriate db.

Answer (score 0):

For the results you specify, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when account = 'A'
             then amount * 1.0 / sum(case when account = 'B' then amount end) over (partition by cc)
             else 0
        end) as ratio
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a regular group by with some cases:

```
with cc_amts as (
select cc,
    sum(case when account = 'A' then amount else 0 end) amt_a,
    sum(case when account = 'B' then amount else 0 end) amt_b
from t
group by cc)
select cc, amt_a / amt_b
from cc_amts;
```